# SQLLITE move column and its data from TableA to TableB

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, database-migration, android-room

i have two tables below

table_a with columns (id, table_bId, name, address, postcode, allowedPermisions)

table_b with columns (id, type, level, info)

I want to create a migration strategy as we now supposed to store the allowedPermissions data in table_b instead

Here is what i tried:

```
UPDATE table_a, table_b
SET table_a.allowedPermissions = table_b.allowedPermissions 
WHERE table_b.id=table_a.table_bId;
```

I get a syntax error after UPDATE table_a, (saw an example here saying you can update more than one table?)

I then tried another approach by creating the new column allowedPermissions  using

```
ALTER TABLE table_b
ADD COLUMN allowedPermissions TEXT
```

But how do i copy contents of allowedPermissions  in table_a to table_b in sqlite?

Answer (score 1):

## Answer

I believe that the update would be :-

```
UPDATE table_b SET allowedPermissions = (SELECT allowedPermisions FROM table_a WHERE table_a.table_bId = table_b.id);
```

## Additional

You could then perhaps use :-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_a_copy  AS  SELECT id, table_bId, name, address, postcode FROM table_a;
ALTER TABLE table_a RENAME TO table_a_old;
ALTER TABLE table_a_copy RENAME TO table_a;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_a_old;
```

To remove the redundant **allowedPermisions** column from **table_a**

## Example

Consider the following demonstration :-

```
-- Create the original tables
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_a;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_b;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_a (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, table_bId INTEGER, name TEXT, address TEXT, postcode TEXT, allowedPermisions TEXT);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_b (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, type TEXT, level INTEGER, info TEXT);

-- Populate the original tables
INSERT INTO table_b (type,level,info) VALUES
    ('TYEPA',1,'BLAH A'),('TYEPB',2,'BLAH B'),('TYEPC',1,'BLAH ')
;

INSERT INTO table_a (table_bId, name, address, postcode, allowedPermisions) VALUES
  (1,'Name A','ADDRESS A','OX120ND','READ'),
    (1,'Name M','ADDRESS M','SW050ND','READ'),
  (1,'Name X','ADDRESS X','FA120ND','READ'),
    (2,'Name Z','ADDRESS Z','OX120ND','WRITE')
;

-- Show what table_b looks like before the alter and update
SELECT * FROM table_b;

-- Alter an update table_b
ALTER TABLE table_b ADD COLUMN allowedPermissions;
UPDATE table_b SET allowedPermissions = (SELECT allowedPermisions FROM table_a WHERE table_a.table_bId = table_b.id);

-- Show what table_b looks like after the alter and update
SELECT * FROM table_b;

-- Clean up table_a (remove the allowdPermisions column)
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_a_copy;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_a_copy  AS  SELECT id, table_bId, name, address, postcode FROM table_a;
ALTER TABLE table_a RENAME TO table_a_old;
ALTER TABLE table_a_copy RENAME TO table_a;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_a_old;
SELECT * FROM table_a;
```

## Example Result

The first result (table_b before the alter and update):-

[image]

The second result (table_b after the alter and update) :-

[image]

- 3rd row is an orphan (by intention) hence the NULL

The third result (table_a without the allowedPermisions column) :-

[image]

Comment: brilliant thanks. i will try these suggestions. thanks!

Comment: kind of worked but it did not copy the foreign key constrains

Comment: @jonney really? it did all of the ones that you specified in the question.

Comment: I have foreign key constraints on my production level table specifying stuff like cascade etc. I guess I have to write the ftrkuh) foreign key constrains as part of the create table statement

Comment: @jonney Yes, unless you extract and manipulate the sql from the sql column of sqlite_master for the table and **BUT** room won't allow you to do that, so you'd have to do that before you do the RoomDatabase build by opening an SQliteDatabase from the non-room SDK. However, I don't believe the it's worth such an effort though as the manipulation could be awkward.